# How to re-evaluate and apply init.el?

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I'd like to make changes to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` that change my key bindings for clojure/cider mode and re-evaluate these changes without having to quit/restart emacs. This would make it easy to iteratively test new keybindings.

I mention clojure/cider specifically, but I haven't gotten this to work with modes other than emacs-lisp mode (i.e. org mode).

Comment: See also https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To reevaluate the entire init file type `M-x eval-buffer` in a buffer visiting it, or `M-: (load-file user-init-file)` to reload without visiting it.

However, if your intention is to iteratively add new keybindings or code to your running Emacs session I recommend not to evaluate the entire buffer but instead use `C-M-x` (aka `eval-defun`) to evaluate only the current function or top-level definition or `M-x eval-region` to evaluate selected code.

Comment: That is good advice. If you are in the habit of regularly reloading your entire init file, you should take care to ensure that it is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), or you may get all kinds of unexpected results.